# Cast to INT Fails

Tags: sql, sql-server

I executed a query very similar to this:

```
SELECT
     CAST(A.ValueCol AS INT) * CAST(B.ValueCol AS INT) MultipliedValue
FROM Table1 A
JOIN Table1 B
     ON A.LinkCol = B.LinkCol
WHERE
     A.TypeCol = <Value that limits ValueCol to only integers>
     AND B.TypeCol = <Value that limits ValueCol to only integers>
```

In this case, `ValueCol` is type NVARCHAR and contains both integer and non-integer values. Despite adequate filtering in the WHERE clause, I'm getting CAST errors for values that aren't even scoped (e.g. if WHERE filters all non-integer values, SQL is throwing an error trying to cast 'ABC', which does exist in a table row but should not have been pulled into this query). I verified that only integer values were being pulled by removing the CASTs and selecting the two `ValueCol`s independently.

Is there a precedence/order of operations problem here? Is CAST applied to all rows' `ValueCol`s prior to filtering with WHERE?

I know I can use TRY_CAST, just curious about this behavior in SQL. Thank you!

Comment: In short yes, you can't predict how many rows SQL Server will attempt to evaluate your condition on, but its not restricted to the rows you want returned. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. When you have your situation you need to write your query to handle the possibility of bad data.

Comment: This very much depends on the resulting execution plan and where the predicate is applied. A possible workaround might be to use a *rowgoal* but ultiumately it's the design at fault.

Comment: Similar issue noted [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/301650/220697) with `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`. Essentially the compiler is free to evaluate expressions anywhere in the query tree, the only way around it is to use `CASE` or functions like `NULLIF`, and in your case `TRY_CAST` is the best option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, SQL Server will deem it more efficient to run an operation like `CAST()` for every row in a page (or index), *before* applying filters from the `WHERE` clause.

*There is no good way to avoid this*.

This is one reason why you should not store meaningful data in columns with an ambiguous type, with anti-patterns such as EAV.

Comment: `TRY_CAST` is an obvious workaround...

Comment: @Charlieface What I meant was running the function on every row. That still happens with `Try_Cast()`. It's just that `Try_Cast()` doesn't cause the whole query to fail if the conversion doesn't work.